# Set default font for received and unstyled HTML messages in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, html, microsoft-outlook-2013, default-settings

Many mail programs (Thunderbird, for instance) and mailing lists send HTML mail without additional CSS or inline styles, leaving it to the mail client to decide what font to choose.

In Outlook 2010 and 2013, such messages are rendered by default with Times New Roman. This is similar to the default in Internet Explorer. In the latter I can change the default under Options to be Arial, but in Outlook there is no such setting, nor could I find one in the registry or in online forums.

Note: this is *not* the same as the default font for outgoing mail [or the default font for incoming plaintext messages](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1463-outlook-change-font-size-color.html).

This is particularly annoying when replying to mail: Outlook then inserts a CSS style for `MsoNormal` defaulting to `Times New Roman` and setting that style for the inserted message, and then inserts inline CSS for the rest of your reply. Result: anybody receiving your message reply will see their own messagebody in *your* default Times font, which is not pretty for screenreaders. In fact, it is just plain annoying.

Does anyone know of a solution or add-in that resolves this behavior?

Comment: I have the same problem and this problem still persists on MS Outlook 2013. I edited the "2013"-part into your question since it doesn't really change the question.

Comment: Very sad that it's not possible at all. There are instructions on the web for Outlook 2007+ but they don't actually apply to 2010 anymore. What a primitive e-mail application that is.