# How can I change the default font used for displaying the content of unstyled messages in Outlook back to Calibri?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts

How can I change the default font used for displaying the content of unstyled messages in Outlook back to Calibri?

I say "unstyled" here meaning HTML messages sent without a font setting, as distinct from plain text messages.

**What I have tried:**

- I know [how to change the default font for composing messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-or-set-the-default-font-in-outlook-20f72414-2c42-4b53-9654-d07a92b9294a): File -> Options -> Mail -> Stationery and Fonts. This works fine.
- And in that same dialog box, when I select the "Composing and reading plain text messages" font, I can change the font for reading plaintext messages.
- But when I look at unstyled HTML messages, they still show up as the new "Aptos" font, which I do not want to see. Ever.

This includes .msg files I have saved several years ago (2021 or earlier) in version control, so the binary content of the message has not changed, only the way Microsoft Outlook has chosen to display them, and I cannot figure out how to change that display setting for default fonts.

This is "Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20194) 64-bit".

I have Calibri selected for all the settings (see below). I've tried changing themes. I've tried restarting Outlook. I've rebooted my computer. No luck.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this and tried it? https://superuser.com/questions/388301/change-outlooks-default-view-font-setting

Comment: Have you looked at that question? It is from 2012 and applies to Outlook 2010.

Comment: Anyway that question applies to the font used in the Outlook UI, not the font used for displaying message content.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-or-set-the-default-font-in-outlook-20f72414-2c42-4b53-9654-d07a92b9294a). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I've seen that already, that's exactly what I mentioned I already did in the question description.

Comment: When you note that you went to File > Options > Mail > Stationary and Fonts, please confirm that you changed the option at the bottom of that dialog "Composing and reading plain text messages". Also, what version of Outlook are you running?

Comment: I'll edit my post with a screen shot. I've tried closing and restarting Outlook, no luck. Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20194) 64-bit

Comment: OK, it's not plaintext messages, it's HTML messages with unstyled text.

Comment: Roughly the same as https://superuser.com/questions/776513/set-default-font-for-received-and-unstyled-html-messages-in-outlook but nobody answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Outlook doesn’t provide a direct option to set a default font for unstyled HTML messages. The font used to display these messages is typically determined by the email client’s rendering engine.

However, when you reply to these messages, Outlook may insert a CSS style for the inserted message, and then inserts inline CSS for the rest of your reply. This could result in the recipient seeing their own message body in your default font.

While it’s not an ideal solution, you could manually change the font when composing or replying to an email. If you often need to read unstyled HTML messages in a specific font, you might want to consider using an email client that allows you to set a default font for unstyled HTML messages
​

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at (what were text based emails) in my Archive from before 2000.

For mail in Inbox or Folders (not a new Message), the font is not adjustable (even now in Outlook 365).

But Outlook now uses a font to display plain text.  I cannot see what font however it could be the new "Aptos" font as you suggest.

From what I can see (working on these old messages I have) there is nothing you can do about the font Outlook has chosen to use.

And also, this is not new.  Outlook has not natively allowed you to edit the font of existing messages for a very long time; or change the default font of messages in a folder.

Comment: Appreciate it, but I don't want to edit the font of existing messages, I want to change the setting for how the default message is displayed.

Comment: You cannot do that.  I clarified my answer about this. @Faery